# finding total no. of subgroups of a group

Tags: normal-subgroups

How do we find the total no. Of subgroups of a group, in Zn,Sn,An,Dn?
And there's this theorem that if 'a' belongs to Group G,then  is a subgroup of G. Does that mean that we already hve available subgroups equal to the no. Of elements in the group.

Comment: "And there's this theorem that if 'a' belongs to Group G,then is a subgroup of G". I don't recall ever reading such nonsense. The conclusion you wish to draw from it is false, since $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ has just two subgroups.

Comment: You may be thinking of "If $a$ is an element of a group $G$, then the set generated by $a$ (*labelled as $\langle a\rangle$ and defined as $\{a^n~:~n\in\Bbb Z\}=\{\dots,a^{-2},a^{-1},e,a^1,a^2,\dots\}$ using multiplicative notation*) is a subgroup of $G$"  The problem with your conclusion is that not every choice of $a$ determines a unique subgroup.  A subgroup could have multiple generators.

Comment: I recall, perhaps incorrectly, that the problem of finding the number of subgroups of $S_n$ is very hard. For $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the number of subgroups is the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: Okay...if i were to find the no. Of subgroups of a certain order say 7 of a group of order 168. What is the procedure to be followed?